# Facebook: Add Login Permissions for Development

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a facebook app with a secure canvas url.

Is it possible to add login permissions without having to have the app approved?
I need the permissions for development reasons, the app is still not available to public.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All users with a defined Role in your App (Administrators, Developers, etc) can conceded all the permissions without having the application approved by Facebook.

Source:

- [Do I Need to Submit for Login Review?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review)

Comment: How come after login I get an empty invitable friends list?

Comment: Are your app a game that have a canvas version?

Comment: Yes, and I'm testing from within facebook